# Can't import pxssh from pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

i'm trying to import pxssh from pexpect. But i get the following error, and i dont know how to solve this.

```
>>> from pexpect import pxssh

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pexpect\pxssh.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pexpect import ExceptionPexpect, TIMEOUT, EOF, spawn
ImportError: cannot import name 'spawn'
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is something wrong in your environment... maybe you have a different file called `pexpect.py` in your local directory? Do `import pexpect;pexpect.__file__`. It should be `/...something.../pexpect/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your Pexpect version is something like 2.3, if so, you need to update the package to 4.2 or greater. To do it run the following:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade pexpect
```

Comment: My Pexpect version is 2.3 and when I execute this statement, it doesn't upgrade it to any higher version. It says, "Best match: pexpect 2.3". My Python version is 2.7.5. Should my Python version be higher to upgrade Pexpect?